# Necessary Sample Size for Negative Binomial Regressions?

Tags: sample-size, nonlinear-regression, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm running a series of negative binomial regressions, each with 5 predictors, and I am concerned that one of my models only has 161 cases. Are there any citations or guidelines on sample size for these types of models? I could do some power analyses but with my dependent variable being limited, I am concerned this won't give me great information.

Thanks so much for looking at this!

All best, Frances

Comment: There nothing special about the negative binomial as far as sample size is concerned. The principles are the same as for normal or gamma regression. Why would you think that 161 cases isn't enough for 5 predictors? Power depends on variability as well as on sample size, so it's not possible to give guidelines without knowing something more about your data. However 161 seems plenty. If that's not enough, then your cases must be very variable indeed.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I agree that 161 cases should be enough, but I've seen a formula for logistic regression to calculate the necessary sample size (N = 10 * k / p; k = Xs & p = % of positive cases). Since my dependent variable is also limited would I need a special way to calculate the sample size? Also when I've dichotomized continuous outcomes I lost power and sometimes previously significant variables became not significant. Is logistic regression the only limited dependent variable that needs extra considerations?

Comment: Negative binomial regression isn't the same a binary regression. The dependent variable has an infinite range and therefore isn't limited. The only exception would be when most of the counts are zero, but your question doesn't mention that as an issue. At my place of work we frequently run 10's of thousands, or even millions, of negative binomial regressions at a time and our sample sizes are usually much smaller than yours.

Comment: Another avenue would be to look carefully for batch effects or unmodeled variation, which often impact on power far more than minor changes in the sample size.